# R - apply function to columns meet certain criteria

Tags: r, multiple-columns, lapply

I set a function like this:

```
numdate <- function(x) {if(!all(is.na(as.Date(as.character(x),
format="%Y%m%d")))) {
as.Date(as.character(x),format="%Y%m%d")}
else return (x)}
```

The purpose is to identify columns contains data like "20161213", and change it to date "2016-12-13".

```
   ValueDate BookDate TranAmt
1  20161219  20161219 189887.5
2  20161216  20161216 20151212
3  20161216  20161216 19229923
```

What I want is

```
   ValueDate   BookDate    TranAmt
1  2016-12-19  2016-12-19  189887.5
2  2016-12-16  2016-12-16  20151212
3  2016-12-16  2016-12-16  192299.23
```

So R only changes the first two date columns and leave the 3rd column as it is (I do not know which column is date and which column is not)

```
d3 <- lapply(d1, numdate)
```

changes all the value to date which is something I don't like

Comment: Instead of `!all` I think you want `!any` (or `all(!is.na)`). `!all(is.na())` will be TRUE as long as at least one  element works as a data, like `20151212` does in your example. Instead, I think you want to test if there are any `NA`. Also you are missing an `r` in `character`.

Comment: A clearer structure might be `if (any(is.na(as.Date(as.character(x))))) return(x) else format(...)`.